# Unity C# Script for ARKit app throws NullReferenceException when calling a function

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, arkit

I am running this C# script in Unity 3D for an iOS ARkit app.  When `Update()` is called, it executes a function `UpdatePlacementPose()`.  I immediately get error logs that say

```
update 2
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log(LogType, LogOption, String, Object)
UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat(LogType, Object, String, Object[])
UnityEngine.Logger:Log(LogType, Object)
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
ARTapToPlaceObject:Update()

(Filename: ./Runtime/Export/Debug/Debug.bindings.h Line: 35)

NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  at ARTapToPlaceObject.UpdatePlacementPose () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at ARTapToPlaceObject.Update () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 

(Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)
```

I am confused because the function I am calling does not need an instance of an object to be called. Here is the c# script that I wrote:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;
using UnityEngine.XR;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems;
using System;

public class ARTapToPlaceObject : MonoBehaviour
{
  public GameObject objectToPlace;
  public GameObject placementIndicator;
  private Camera myCamera;
  private ARSessionOrigin arOrigin;
  private ARRaycastManager raycastManager;
  private Pose placementPose;
  private bool placementPoseIsValid = false;

  private void UpdatePlacementIndicator()
  {
      if (placementPoseIsValid)
      {
          placementIndicator.SetActive(true);
          placementIndicator.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(placementPose.position, placementPose.rotation);
      }
      else
      {
          placementIndicator.SetActive(false);
      }
  }

  private void UpdatePlacementPose()
  {
      var screenCenter = Camera.main.ViewportToScreenPoint(new Vector3(0.5f, 0.5f));
      var hits = new List<ARRaycastHit>();
      raycastManager.Raycast(screenCenter, hits, TrackableType.Planes);
      Debug.Log("Screen: " +  screenCenter);
      Debug.Log("Hits: " +  hits);
      Debug.Log("Planes: " + TrackableType.Planes);

      placementPoseIsValid = hits.Count > 0;
      if (placementPoseIsValid)
      {
          placementPose = hits[0].pose;
          Debug.Log("Hits Pose: " + hits[0].pose);


          // var cameraForward = Camera.current.transform.forward;
          // var cameraBearing = new Vector3(cameraForward.x, 0, cameraForward.z).normalized;
          // placementPose.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(cameraBearing);
      }
  }


  void Start()
  {
      arOrigin = FindObjectOfType<ARSessionOrigin>();
      raycastManager = FindObjectOfType<ARRaycastManager>();

  }

  void Update()
  {
      Debug.Log("update 2");
      UpdatePlacementPose();
      Debug.Log("after updated placement pose");

      UpdatePlacementIndicator();

      if (placementPoseIsValid &&  Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
      {
          PlaceObject();
      }
  }

  private void PlaceObject()
  {
      Instantiate(objectToPlace, placementPose.position, placementPose.rotation);
  }


}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The exception is thrown because one instance used in the `UpdatePlacementPose` method is `null`. For example, if `raycastManager` is null, `raycastManager.Raycast` call throws a null reference exception.